# How to (dynamically) change Java stream's filter conditions?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, predicate

I have a few classes of the following general form, where `this.words` is a `List<String>` containing one word per element:

```
public ArrayList<String> wordsInclZ() {
    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<>();

    this.words.stream()
        .filter(word -> word.contains("z"))
        .forEach(word -> results.add(word));

    return results;
}
```

The only bit I have to change are the filter conditions, i.e., the expression inside `.filter()`. This doesn't appear to be a terrible copy-paste situation, however I'd like to learn if it was possible to write neater code.

Is there a concise way to generalize this functionality? I guess I'm basically asking can I and how should I pass the lambda to the `.filter()` as a parameter of a general method that handles the rest of the above method's functionality.

Comment: Additionally : You can use .collect(Collectors.toList()); instead of forEach. Then return the collect's result. No need to define empty result list.(for your functionality)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a parameter for your function:

```
Predicate<String> predicate
```

You can then pass the filter to your function:

```
wordsInclZ(word -> word.contains("z"));
```

And the filter would be:

```
filter(predicate);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the perfect solution! Here's what I ended up with, in case someone could use it: `return this.words.stream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));`

Comment: Not to be fussy but one can shave a few chars off by changing the final collect to collect(Collectors.toList()).

Answer (score 2):

There are two options here:

1. Passing a method reference to a method that takes an actual value and returns a `boolean` result:

   ```
   public boolean filter1(String s) {
       return s.contains("z");
   }
   // .filter(this::filter1)
   ```
2. Returning a `Predicate` from a method:

   ```
   public Predicate<String> filter2() {
       return s -> s.contains("z");
   }
   // .filter(filter2())
   ```

Answer (score 1):

**You can create a function and pass it to the filter as a parameter:**

```
public ArrayList<String> wordsInclZ() {
    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<>();

    this.words.stream()
         .filter(MyClass::myFilterFunction)
         .forEach(word -> results.add(word));

     return results;
}

private static boolean myFilterFunction(String word){
    // do whatever you need and return TRUE or FALSE
}
```